# Как на heroku узнать часы Dynos?

Tags: консоль, heroku

Как узнать сколько осталось всего часов на heroku *(на самом аккаунте)* **через консоль**?
Какая команда служит для этого?

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [официальной документации](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#determining-your-free-dyno-hours),

> это можно сделать через Heroku CLI командой `heroku ps` в одном из ваших бесплатных
> приложений.

Полная команда выглядит так:

`heroku ps -a your-app-name`

Результат:

```
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 1000h 0m (100%)
Free dyno usage for this app: 0h 0m (0%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

=== web (Free): node index.js (1)
web.1: up 2021/10/01 10:58:37 +0300 (~ 1h ago)
```

Другие варианты того, как узнать часы Dynos, перечислены [тоже на официальной странице heroku](https://help.heroku.com/FRHZA2YG/how-do-i-monitor-my-free-dyno-hours-quota). Например, остаток часов можно посмотреть в Heroku Dashboard [в разделе Billing](https://dashboard.heroku.com/account/billing).

Comment: А при этом Dynos смотрится у конкретного приложения или у всего аккаунта?

Comment: Аккаунта. Чтобы увидеть часы отдельно по приложениям, зайдите в Billing, там под общим числом часов будет список Ваших приложений с указанием кол-ва часов каждого.